# Создание пользовательского интерфейса

Tags: winapi, gui, ui

Можно ли создать пользовательский(нормальный, красивый) интерфейс без WinAPI?

---

Т.е можно ли создать что-то подобное без winAPI и с помощью каких технологий?
[image: Т.е можно ли создать что-то подобное без winAPI и с помощью каких технологий?]

---

> Если вопрос глупый или уже есть статья с ответом — извиняюсь, просто сейчас думаю, что будет перебором учить winAPI только ради такого.

Comment: P.s: Я знаю, что модель в центре не через winAPI создавать, я конкретно про панели вокруг.

Comment: Без WinAPI это как? Фреймворков разных много, но все они внутри используют WinAPI. А чтобы совсем без использования WinAPI, то никак наверное.

Comment: @freim Сложно объянить, но попробую: При создании окна с помощью чисто winAPI приходится вписывать слишком много деталей, мне для простенького окна понадобилось 236 строк кода, мне не обязательно чисто без winAPI, но чтобы функции были более абстрактны.

Comment: Ну так используйте любой фреймворк для языка на котором пишете, в чем проблема-то? На чистом апи никто и не пишет в наши дни.